# D3 axis and bar transition not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Lost on this especially since I've done it successfully before. The code below is within a function called on a click. This first example works just fine:

```
y.domain([1, get_max(data)]);

svg.select('.y.axis')
    .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll('.bars')
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y(d); })
    .attr('height', function (d) { return height - y(d); });
```

This second example doesn't do anything:

```
y.domain([1, get_max(data)]);

svg.select('.y.axis')
    .transition()
    .duration(80)
    .call(yAxis);

svg.selectAll('.bars')
    .transition()
    .duration(80)
    .attr('y', function (d) { return y(d); })
    .attr('height', function (d) { return height - y(d); });
```

No javascript errors are produced. It simply doesn't do anything.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Note: get_max(data) is a special function to get the max of some very oddly formatted data. When I replace it with a hard coded value of 10,000 the problem persists. Again it works fine until I add the transition.

**EDIT:**

```
function render(parent, data, brands){
        var time_format = parent.attr('data-chart-size') > 3 ? '%b %e' : '%e',
            margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 21, left: 45 },
            width = parent.width() - margin.left - margin.right - 110; // -110 for the legends on the right side

        height = 205 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var x = d3.time.scale().domain([ML._dates.start(), ML._dates.end()]).range([0, width]);

        y = d3.scale.log().clamp(true).range([height, 1]);

        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient('bottom')
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format(time_format)).tickSize(0).tickPadding(8);

        yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient('left').ticks(5, 's').tickSize(0);

        svg = d3.select(parent.get(0)).append('svg')
            .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append('g')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

        var brands_length = brands.length,
            values_length = data.posts[brands[0]].values.length,

            bar_width_adjustment = 60 / values_length,
            bar_width = ((width / values_length) / brands_length) - bar_width_adjustment;

        range_band = width / values_length;

        y.domain([1, get_max(data)]);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'x axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (bar_width * 2) + ',' + height + ')')
            .call(xAxis);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('class', 'y axis')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 0)')
            .call(yAxis);

        // BUILD THE BARS AND TOOLTIP HIGHLIGHT AREA
        for(var brands_loop = 0; brands_loop < brands_length; ++brands_loop){
            svg.selectAll('.chart-hover')
                .data(data.posts[brands[brands_loop]].values)
                .enter().append('rect')
                .attr('width', width / values_length)
                .attr('x', function (d, i) { return i * range_band - ((range_band - bar_width * 3) / 2); })
                .attr('y', 1)
                .attr('height', height - y(y.domain()[1]))
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ((bar_width * (brands_loop + 1) - (bar_width / 2)) + ', 0)'))
                .attr('data-index', function (d, i) { return i; })
                .attr('class', 'chart-hover')
                .style('opacity', 0.01);

            svg.selectAll('.bar-' + brands_loop)
                .data(data.posts[brands[brands_loop]].values)
                .enter().append('rect')
                .attr('data-legend-listener-brand', brands[brands_loop])
                .attr('data-legend-listener-metric', 'posts')
                .attr('data-hover-dispatcher-index', function (d, i) { return i; })
                .attr('width', bar_width)
                .attr('x', function (d, i) { return i * range_band; })
                .attr('y', function (d) { return y(d); })
                .attr('height', function (d) { return height - y(d); })
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + ((bar_width * (brands_loop + 1) - (bar_width / 2)) + ', 0)'))
                .attr('class', 'posts bars bar-' + brands_loop);

            // POPULATE LEGEND TEXTS FOR POSTS, EXPOSURE AND ENGAGEMENT
            $('.brand-' + (brands_loop + 1))
                .text(data.posts[brands[brands_loop]].label)
                .attr('data-legend-brand', brands[brands_loop])
                .attr('data-legend-listener-brand', brands[brands_loop])
                .prev('i')
                .attr('data-legend-brand', brands[brands_loop])
                .attr('data-legend-listener-brand', brands[brands_loop]);
        }
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Looks like it should work. Could you provide a complete example that reproduces the problem please?

Comment: Yes, it's rather frustrating. I'll edit and post the beginning of the function that renders the axis/bars in the first place.

Comment: Hmm, are you adding the transition inside the loop? In that case it'll be overwritten. You shouldn't be using a loop anyway but [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: No, the transitions only exist in the second example. I'll have to get more accustomed to nested selections, I'm betting that would make my life easier. I did it this way because I was having trouble getting proper grouped bar charts working and I'm very much pressed for time. Really quite upsetting that this won't just animate the transition.

Comment: We'll really need to see a complete example that demonstrates the problem.